# postgres: how to call a function that returns a table and pass params from a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, set-returning-functions, lateral

As an instant example:

#### A function that returns a table:

```
=> create or replace function testf(x integer)
     returns table(a integer, b integer)
   language sql
   as $function$
       select * from (values(1,2)) as foo(a,b)
   $function$;
```

#### Calling it so it returns a record (or whatever you call it):

```
=> select testf(3);
 testf
-------
 (1,2)
```

#### Calling it so it returns a table (good):

```
=> select * from  testf(3);
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
```

#### But how do I call it so the parameters come from a query?

```
=> select s.n, testf(s.n) from (select 3 as n union select 4) s;
 n | testf
---+-------
 3 | (1,2)
 4 | (1,2)            <-- not a table (or row with column names)


=> select * from  testf(s.n) from (select 3 as n) s;
```

> ```
>  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
>  LINE 1: select * from  testf(s.n) from (select 3 as n) s;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (VALUES (3), (4)) AS s(n)
     , testf(s.n);
```

The comma is short notation for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, since `LATERAL` is assumed automatically with set-returning functions in the `FROM` clause.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)